# Unable to locate package realsense2_camera for Foxy

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I'm wondering, why I'm not able to find/install realsense2_camera package for ROS2 Foxy. The package is not found by the command

```
sudo apt-get install ros-foxy-realsense2-camera

E: Unable to locate package ros-foxy-realsense2-camera
```

However, `realsense2_camera_msgs` and `realsense2_descriptions` are found, but according to ROS Index, the `realsense2_camera` should be also found.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/379278/unable-to-locate-package-realsense2_camera-for-foxy/) by [ahopsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/75387/ahopsu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2021-05-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-05-31**:
Could you check whether you're running into #q379190?

A `sudo apt update` should error with a key expired problem.

**Comment by [ahopsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/75387/ahopsu/) on 2021-05-31**:
I had this issue also earlier on the day, but it shoudl be solved now, sudo `apt(-get) update` is working. And I think, that these problems are not related to each other.

When I type `sudo apt-get install ros-foxy-realsense` and press tab button twice, I get the list of the following available packages:

```
ros-foxy-realsense2-camera-msgs
ros-foxy-realsense2-camera-msgs-dbgsym
ros-foxy-realsense2-description
ros-foxy-realsense-msgs
ros-foxy-realsense-msgs-dbgsym
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit: with the [sync of 2021-06-03](https://discourse.ros.org/t/new-packages-for-foxy-fitzroy-2021-06-03/20770), `realsense2_camera` should now be available from the main repositories.

---

According to [status_page/ros_foxy_default.html?q=realsense](http://repo.ros2.org/status_page/ros_foxy_default.html?q=realsense), `realsense2_camera` is not available in the `main` repositories yet (notice the red square in the right-most column).

That would explain why you can't install it using `apt`.

As to *why* it isn't available, I wouldn't know.

It seems to be available in the testing repository though. How to set that up is sort-of documented on this page: [Pre-release Testing: Debian testing repository](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Installation/Prerelease-Testing.html#debian-testing-repository).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahopsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/75387/ahopsu/) on 2021-05-31**:
Thank you for the info! At least now I know, what is causing this issue.